# How to parameterize a quadric surface of the form $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=yz$

Tags: geometry, polynomials

I am trying to find the solutions of an equation of the form,
$$ax^2+by^2+cz^2=yz$$
For $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, where $a,b,c$ are real and non-zero. So far i've considered dividing it up into cases depending on the sign of the constants, so that the LHS would represent an ellipsoid or hyperboloid.

Of course the LHS would only become that if we added say 1 to both sides, however then this isn't as simple of solving $f(x)=g(x)$ but looking at the intersections of $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, as these would then become 4 dimensional functions.

If anyone could give any tips or advice i'd greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: By 'solve', I mean find the solution space, so how to parametrically describe this surface.

Comment: $ax^2 + b\left(y-\frac{z}{2b}\right)^2 + \left(c - \frac{1}{4b}\right)z^2 = 0$ (if $b\neq 0$).

Comment: What do you mean by _solution_ of the equation ?

Comment: I am asking just which is the solution space: $\Bbb {R}^3$ ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I will specify that. Yes, $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Yours is the equation of a _quadric_: except some cases (I didn't check), the solutions are many ...

Comment: Hmmm ok, thanks, so I should be able to parameterize it?

Comment: Sure, quadrics are rational parametric surfaces.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo: Excellent, I will have a go at that.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I did get that result, how would you recommend getting from that to some way of describing the surface?

Comment: The type of the surface depends on the signs of the coefficients. If $4bc = 1$, we have a quadric $ax^2+b\eta^2=0$ (with a change of coordinates, $\eta=y-z/(2b)$), and that is the $z$-axis if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, and the union of two planes intersecting in the $z$-axis if the signs are opposite; in the original coordinates, the figure is sheared. If $4bc\neq 1$, we have an equation $ax^2+b\eta^2+\gamma z^2=0$, and that is a single point (the origin) if all signs of the coefficients are equal, and an elliptic cone if not all signs are equal. Again shear for original coordinates.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you! That is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a homogenous equation, substitute $(x,y,z)=(x,ux,vx)$ to obtain

$$a+bu^2+cv^2=uv\iff bu^2-uv+cv^2=-a.$$ ($\Delta =1-4bc$). If you want rational solutions, suppose you already have some point on the curve $(u_0,v_0)$. Put $(u,v)=(u'-u_0,v'-v_0)$ to obtain
$$bu'^2-2bu'u_0-u'v'+v_0u'+u_0v'+cv'^2-2cv'v_0=0,$$
at which point substitute $v'=u't,$ thus $$bu'^2-2bu'u_0-u'^2t+v_0u'+u_0u't+cu'^2t^2-2cu'v_0t=0$$or$$(b-t+ct^2)u'-2bu_0+v_0+u_0t-2cv_0t=0$$ and $$u'(t)=\frac{2bu_0-v_0+(-u_0+2cv_0)t}{b-t+ct^2}.$$ Otherwise you want a parametrization that's not necessarily rational. So we're looking to find
$(u,v)$. Factor the left hand side like so:

$$b\left(u-\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4bc}}{b}v\right)\left(u-\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4bc}}{b}v\right)=-a$$ and assume $$bu-(1+\sqrt{1-4bc})v=-aw$$$$u-\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4bc}}{b}v=-\frac{a}{w}$$ when $\Delta \geqslant 0,$ or notice for $\Delta<0$ that

$$(lu+mv)^2+(nu+ov)^2=(l^2+n^2)u^2+2(lm+no)uv+(m^2+o^2)v^2$$ so that

$$l=\sqrt{b}\sin\alpha ,n=\sqrt{b}\cos\alpha$$
$$m=\sqrt{c}\sin\beta ,o=\sqrt{c}\cos\beta$$ where
$$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{bc}}, \text{ so }\alpha-\beta\in\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$$ or equivalently all other intervals differing by $2\pi k$. Either way you end up with parametrizations. You could even let $$\tan \frac{\alpha}{2}=\tau,\tan\frac{\beta}{2}=\tau'$$ to tie it all together. You can analogously derive the case for the hyperbolic sine and cosine for the form $X^2-Y^2.$